# Why does this SQL ODBC query not work?

Tags: sql, odbc

How come this SQL Statement doesn't work?

```
Select 'event2' as 'EVENTCOLN'
```

The error comes out as:

[Honeywell][ODBC Driver]Expected lexical element not found:

If I try

```
Select 'event2'
```

The error comes out as:

[Honeywell][ODBC Driver]Unexpected end of SQL statement

I have tried many other variations all doesn't seem to work.

I just want the database to spit out a value 'event2'

FYI, i'm connecting to an ODBC Driver called 'Experion PKS ODBC Driver'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Select 'event2' as EVENTCOLN
```

or

```
Select 'event2' as "EVENTCOLN"
```

You're using a string literal as a column name.

If your ODBC driver doesn't support selecting values without a table name, select a random table and select the TOP 1:

```
SELECT TOP 1 'event2' AS EVENTCOLN FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks, but neither works. it says [Honeywell][ODBC Driver]Unexpected end of SQL statement

Comment: That driver may not support selecting a value without a table name.  you may need to pick a random table to use as the source.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works when I don't specify top: like SELECT 'event2' AS EVENTCOLN FROM event2. Is there any special format for top?

Comment: Forget about it. THe Top statement is not supported by this driver. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that driver specifically, but

```
Select 'event2'
```

is not a complete SQL statement - thus the unexpected end. If I wanted to just get a value for 'event2', I would try something like:

```
SELECT event2 FROM <tablename>;
```

I don't know about the single quotes you had on 'event2' - unless it's a very unique driver, you don't want quotes on the column name. Also, note I added "FROM " to specify the table that has the 'event2' column.

I added a semicolon - some drivers/databases want that and others don't - you might try both ways.

Comment: Thanks, but I just want it to spit out the word 'Event2' no querying is done